# Best tool for generating code templates in python

Tags: python

We've developed a system in Python that will load "plugins" made by other people on our corporation. There're a few types of plugins, but within a type, the code template will always be the same.

I was wondering if there's an easy tool for Python that would create the skeleton of the plugin. The tool would have to:

1. Create a dir with the skeleton files (possibly making some template substitutions).
2. Create a git repository in it.
3. Create a remote repository in the company's central git repository (via ssh).
4. Add the remote repository as origin for the local repository.
5. Committing the skeleton files to the remote repository automatically.

Googling, the best tool I found was Paste, but it seems a little overkill, as it's an entire WSGI tool. Is there another tool, possibly more specialized for this task?

Comment: So, you're expecting a complete ready made solution for your fairly specific use case to exist? Good luck with that. Also, Paste isn't even close.

Comment: This looks like 'someone write me a bash script'.

Comment: For this to be a good question, it would have to least all of the applicable approaches you can identify, and ask something concrete and specific. Also, this seems like the kind of task python excels at: integrating a bunch of libraries in a relatively unexpected way. You may find that rolling your own will relatively easy.

Comment: @Lattyware: No, what I mean is instead of creating a bunch of bash script to basically apply seds to the template files, which seems to me to be basically reinvent the wheel, use a template platform that already knows how to do this kind of thing, I'd just use its facilities to define my template and the code for the git part. This can be done with Paste: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pylons-webframework/en/latest/advanced_pylons/creating_paste_templates.html but is not what its intended for.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you'd have to write your own.

Start with a base git repo for point 1. Clone/branch from that for next step. Use [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.3/) for steps 2-5.